# Should I launch workers after starting masters and slaves?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So to launch Spark in a Standalone mode, should I launch workers in master and slaves after starting master and slaves?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use the spark standalone cluster. You have to configure the master and workers of the cluster and then start it.

The official Spark documentation [explains](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) it quite well.
Hint: For testing(having master and worker on the same node), you do not have to configure anything (if the default ports are not already used in your system). Simply call sbin/start-all.sh to start the (one-node) cluster.

You should see the master/worker nodes in the spark standalone cluster UI.

Afterwards you just use spark-submit or other means to run your spark application.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Workers == slaves

You either use a cluster manager like YARN or Mesos to host workers and make them available to run tasks or use `local[*]` mode (default in `spark-shell`) or Spark Standalone.

For now, just `spark-shell` and forget about drivers, masters, workers, slaves, executors. Spend your time on understanding actions, transformations, jobs, stages, tasks, shuffle. The others will come soon.